# How do I get a random object from a list, only once per object?

Tags: python, list, boolean

So I'm making a Quiz where you are given a country and asked to name its capital. It works, but you may be asked the same questions twice in a row or multiple times per game. I want each country to be asked only once per game. I tried a list of booleans(?), the 'Not_used' list, where the idea was that when a question is answered correctly, it will be set to False and not appear again. I does not work. I don't know what to do.

```
import random

hiscore = 46

points = 0

go_on = True

name = 'Mari'

Country = (['Norge', 'Sverige', 'Danmark', 'Island', 'Finland', 'Estland', 'Russland', 'Tyskland', 'Belgia',
        'Latvia', 'Litauen', 'Nederland', 'Frankrike', 'Spania', 'Portugal', 'Italia',
        'Sveits', 'Liechtenstein', 'Monaco', 'USA', 'Ukraina', 'Serbia', 'Kro5atia', 'Bosnia',
        'Hellas', 'Sør-afrika', 'Den demokratiske republikken Kongo', 'Algerie', 'Egypt', 'Somalia', 'Elfenbenskysten',
        'India', 'Kina', 'Mongolia', 'Sør-korea', 'Indonesia', 'Australia', 'Fillipinene',
        'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Peru', 'Kuba', 'Nicaragua', 'Argentina', 'Brasil', 'Chile','Bulgaria','Botswana','Fiji',
        'Georgia','Israel','Liberia','Albania','Andorra','Armenia','Aserbajdsjan','Bangladesh',
        'Belize','Bhutan','Benin','Brunei','Burkina Faso', 'Etiopia','Forente Arabiske emirater','Gabon','Gambia','Guinea',
        'Guinea-Bissau','Haiti','Iran','Irak','Japan','Kamerun','Kasakhstan','Kirgisistan','Komorene','Lesotho',
        'Mali','Myanmar','Nepal','Oman','Qatar'])

Capital = (['Oslo', 'Stockholm', 'København', 'Reykjavik', 'Helsinki', 'Tallin', 'Moskva', 'Berlin', 'Brussel',
             'Riga', 'Vilnius', 'Amsterdam', 'Paris', 'Madrid', 'Lisboa', 'Roma',
             'Bern', 'Vaduz', 'Monaco', 'Washington DC', 'Kiev', 'Beograd', 'Zagreb', 'Sarajevo',
             'Athen', 'Pretoria', 'Kinshasa', 'Alger', 'Kairo', 'Mogadishu', 'Yamoussoukro',
             'New Delhi', 'Beijing', 'Ulan Bator', 'Seoul', 'Jakarta', 'Canberra', 'Manila',
             'Ottawa', 'Mexico By', 'Lima', 'Havanna', 'Managua', 'Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia',
             'Santiago de Chile','Sofia','Gaborone','Suva','Tbilisi','Jerusalem','Monrovia',
             'Tirana','Andorra la Vella','Jerevan','Baku','Dhaka','Belmopan','Thimpu','Porto-Novo','Bandar Seri Begawan',
             'Ouagadougou','Addis Abeba','Abu Dhabi','Libreville','Banjul','Conakry','Bissau','Port-au-Prince','Teheran',
             'Bagdad','Tokyo','Yaounde','Astana','Bisjkek','Moroni','Maseru','Bamako','Naypyidaw','Katmandu','Muskat','Doha'])


print('Welcom to Capital Quiz!')

print('Remember Uppercase!')

print('Tyy to beat the hiscore =', hiscore,)

print(name,'is the current cahmpion')

k = input("To start press enter")


while go_on:

    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    nr = random.randint(0,80)

    i = input('What is the capital of'+Country[nr]+'? ')

    Not_used = ([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
                 True])

    if i == Capital[nr]:
        points +=1
        Not_used[nr] = False
        print('Correct!')
        print('You currently have',points,'points.')    
    elif i != Country[nr]:
        poeng -=1
        print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print('Worng, the capital of '+Country[nr]+' is ', Capital[nr],'.',sep='')
        go_on = False

print('Did you remeber uppercase?')

print('You scored',points,'points.')

if points > hiscore:

    print('You beat the hiscore! Congratulations!')

elif points < hiscore:

          print('Try to beat the hiscore = ', hiscore,'?', sep='')

          print('Try again!')
```

Comment: Shuffle the list instead, and pick from that shuffled list one by one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that will make it awfully hard to correlate the indices of Countries vs. Capitals though, if they're in separate lists (unless the RNG is explicitely seeded to the same value before shuffling each list).

Comment: But then it might still ask the same question twice?

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude the idea is that you then iterate over the shuffled list in a loop (or `.pop()` items from the shuffled list).

Comment: @LukasGraf: then generate a list of indices. Or use `zip()` and shuffle *that*.

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude: your list now contains the items in random order. Just present them in that order one by one, and you'll never repeat any of them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So if I understand you correctly I will need to generate a list which contains both the countries and the capitals?

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude: that'd be easiest, yes. The `zip()` function would take your two lists and create a new one with the elements paired up. `zip(Country, Capital)` give you a list with `[('Norge', 'Oslo'), ...]`.